# Pushing messages to be spoken to Alexa

Tags: alexa

How do I force Alexa to speak messages? For example everytime someone mentions Elon Musk on Twitter I want my Alexa to automatically speak the tweet.

Comment: (aside, that usecase will rapidly drive you insane as I doubt it would ever stop speaking)